# Can r time series have frequencies greater than a year?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm working with political data based on US Presidential elections, so dates of my values are set four years apart (ie 1980, 1984, 1988, 1992, etc.) However, so far I've only seen examples of time series frequencies being set from anywhere from day to day, month to month, quarterly and annually. Will frequencies of every four years event work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the question is referring to `ts` class, specify frequency = 0.25 or deltat = 4 as in the code below.  In general deltat is the time between adjacent points and frequency = 1/deltat.

```
ts(1:4, start = 1980, deltat = 4)
```

giving:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1980 
End = 1992 
Frequency = 0.25 
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you! That didn't work for my context, but thanks to your confirmation that its possible to create a ts with intervals of 4 years, I experimented and found it works as:
```ts(data,start=1980,end=1992,frequency=.25)``` where data is set as 
```data<-c(1.20, 14.42, 5.97, -3.67, -4.71, -4.24, -5.81, -6.68, -6.71, -6.12, -4.85)```

Comment: The question states your points are 4 years apart but perhaps the question was incorrectly stated and you actually have annual data.  In any case the code in your comment is incorrect.  It will drop some of the data points.

Comment: the interval is definitely four years. I updated the code to ```pvi<-c(1.20, 14.42, 5.97, -3.67, -4.71, -4.24, -5.81, -6.68, -6.71, -6.12, -4.85)

#create the ts object
pvi_by_year<-ts(1:11, start = 1977, deltat = 4)
``` and its working as needed. Thank you!